# PayPal SSL v3 Testing

Tags: payment

PayPal are dropping SSLv3 support in December, how can I ensure my store will still function when this happens.

Are there any tests I can run to check?

Comment: You should check with your hosting provider on whether they still rely on SSLv3 (they shouldn't).

Answer (score 2):

PayPal are merely notifying you that SSLv3 support is being dropped.

Provided your openssl and libcurl libraries are fairly recent, it will gracefully fall back to another method.

You need only check you have client SSLv3 support in your PHP CURL library.

Eg. For CLI/Bash

```
curl --sslv3 -k https://www.paypal.com
```

And for PHP

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.paypal.com");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);

curl_close ($curl);

var_dump($result);
```